# What is the code to save the activePresentation and then close it?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have several open PPT presentations. I have a macro that works fine on any one of them that I choose as the active presentation. What code do I use to 1. Save the Active Presentation. 2. Close the Active Presentation. 3. Go to any open PPT presentation. 4. Run the macro, save, close. 5. Rinse, repeat until the macro has run in all the presentations and closed them.

Comment: Are you running this from one of the presentations that will be closed? That presents a timing problem that wouldn't exist if you are running this from an Add-in.

Comment: Ah. Running from one of the presentations that will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a kludge. Edit line 4 to be the actual name of the macro-enabled presentation holding the macro. The Save/Close loop runs twice, first to catch presentations opened after the one containing the macro and the other to catch presentations opened prior. Then the presentation with macro is saved closed at the end:

```
Sub CloseAll()
  Dim oPresentation As Presentation, ThisPresentation As Presentation
  Dim ThisFile$
  ThisFile$ = "CloseAll.pptm"
  Set ThisPresentation = Application.Presentations(ThisFile$)
  For Each oPresentation In Application.Presentations
    If oPresentation.Name = ThisPresentation.Name Then
    Else
      With oPresentation
        .Save
        .Close
      End With
    End If
  Next oPresentation
  For Each oPresentation In Application.Presentations
    If oPresentation.Name = ThisPresentation.Name Then
    Else
      With oPresentation
        .Save
        .Close
      End With
    End If
  Next oPresentation
  With ThisPresentation
    .Save
    .Close
  End With
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```